# Strange behaviour of NotElement in Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0.**

Confirmed, as bug, by WRI: [CASE:3527549]

---

I have observed curious behaviour on domains supplied to `NotElement` and `Reduce` and domain of an argument in calculation inside `NotElement`:

```
Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + 1/2, Integers], x, Integers]

(* False *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + 1/2, Integers], x, Rationals]

(* x == 1 *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + Sqrt[2], Rationals], x, Rationals]

(* False *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + Sqrt[2], Rationals], x, Algebraics]

(* x == 1 *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + E, Algebraics], x, Algebraics]

(* False *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + E, Algebraics], x, Reals]

(* x == 1 *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + I, Reals], x, Reals]

(* False *)

Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + I, Reals], x, Complexes]

(* x == 1 *)
```

It would seem that these trivial operations result `False` (no solutions exist) when the domain of the added constant in equation inside `NotElement` is in larger domain than one used as an argument of `Reduce`. Does this make sense, or is it actually a bug? If it does make sense, why exactly? To me it seems at best highly unintuitive.

Before someone says that all equations, or constants in equations or domain specifications inside `Reduce` should be at most at the domain supplied to it, consider the following, sensible results when using `Element`:

```
Reduce[x == 1 && Element[x + 1/2, Integers], x, Integers]

(* False *)

Reduce[x == 1 && Element[x + 1/2, Rationals], x, Integers]

(* x == 1 *)
```

---

**EDIT**: To add more hair-splitting semantics leading to hair-pulling, the following variation *does* work nicely:

```
Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + 1/2, Integers], Element[x, Integers]]

(* x == 1 *)
```

I know this only constrains the result, not the domain where solution is sought.

Also, it seems `Reduce` is not particularly picky about out-of-domain constants on other parts of the equation:

```
Reduce[x - E == 1 - E, x, Integers]

(* x == 1 *)
```

So, what (combination of factors) exactly makes `NotElement` so special in the equation part? Is this a very unintuitive feature (particularly as from user perspective, simple `Element` statements seem to work), or should it really be considered to be a bug?

Comment: The documentation for [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html?q=Reduce) says that *Reduce[expr,vars,dom] restricts all variables and parameters to belong to the domain dom.* Since in the first example `1/2` does not belong to `Integers` that makes it `False`. `Reduce[ x== 1 && NotElement[ x + 1/2 ], x]` therefore does what it should do.

Comment: ... you can also validate this *hypotheses* in your third example: `Sqrt[2]` is not a rational making the whole thing `False`.

Comment: @gwr Yes, this is - sort of - what I have suspected, but how is this behaviour - or rather, behaviour of `Element` inside `Reduce` as demonstrated in the end of my question - consistent with this interpretation? I can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: If you use `Trace`you will see what happens with your last two statements:  In the first case (Integers) the `1/2` stays inside the `Reduce`making it false. The condition `Element[ 1/2 + x, Rationals]` though can be reduced to `Element[ x, Rationals ]` since for any Rational this should hold; the `1/2` vanishes making this work out. I admit *unintuitive*. :)

Comment: @gwr This all makes me wonder what's special about `Element` and `NotElement` inside `Reduce`, and how they're handled there. One more example to consider: `Reduce[x - E == 1 - E, x, Integers]` doesn't fail to return the correct answer, and according to `Trace`, the equation is not simplified before it gets passed to `Reduce`.

Comment: @gwr unintuitive is a soft way of saying it... The documentation doesn't exactly say "restricts all variables and parameters... [except those that are obvious to be reduced before being considered by Reduce]. :)

Comment: It's either a bug, or, at least, vague documentation, anyway I think it should be reported to WRI. Did anyone report it already? If yes, please add case number to the question. If not, then I'll report it in the evening.

Comment: @jkuczm I haven't reported it yet. I want to give WRI support some slack - I've written three bug reports in a week, or something like that. So, go ahead (and reference this Mma.SE question in case they would want to participate directly).

Comment: I *think* this has been fixed... `Reduce[x == 1 && NotElement[x + I, Reals], x, Reals]` now behaves correctly. As for the others, variables
and parameters (symbolic) need to belong to the default domain. Constants need to be real if the default domain is contained in Reals.

Comment: @ilian But is that actually sufficiently intuitive? Especially now that old "rule" has an exception.

Comment: @kirma Perhaps I'm not following, the documentation does say "If *dom* is `Reals`, or a subset such as `Integers` or `Rationals`, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."

Comment: @ilian One option would be to make that somewhat hard-to-interpret sentence clearer. How does this affect constants? What is considered to be a constant? Etc...

Comment: @kirma Maybe it could be worded differently and maybe the documentation could have examples... but do you still feel there is a (functionality) bug "persisting through 10.4 or later"?

Comment: @ilian I feel it's a fuzzy issue which could be solved through documentation, or code. Docs, probably.

Comment: @ilian What I meant is that documentation on this regard is not very clear; that statement has been always a bit of "the enigma of SMP" to me, if you know the reference. Further, explicit documentation of what the statement means and how queries such as those I presentend above should be formulated without accidentally falling into an uninteded hole of `False` answer should be clearly present in the product documentation.

Comment: @kirma My bad, there is actually a remaining code issue. It's being fixed today.

Comment: @ilian Oh, that's great!