# A simple expression on which `Reduce` fails

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

The conditions in `x ∉ Integers && y ∈ Integers && y == -(1/2) + x/2` are inconsistent but `Reduce` does not solve it (I expected `False`):

```
cond = x ∉ Integers && y ∈ Integers && y == -(1/2) + x/2;
Reduce[cond, {x, y}]
(*  x ∉ Integers && y ∈ Integers && y == -(1/2) + x/2  *)
```

I thought that odd, since the proof is simple.  I thought I might check that my brain was working correctly by asking for an instance when it's true.  To my surprise, `FindInstance` returned a candidate (a bug apparently), but of course the candidate makes the condition false:

```
FindInstance[cond, {x, y}]
cond /. %
(*
  {{x -> 3909, y -> 1954}}
  {False}
*)
```

It turns out that `Reduce` can solve an equivalent problem (although `FindInstance` produces the same spurious result):

```
Reduce[x ∉ Integers && y ∈ Integers && x == 1 + 2 y]
(*  False  *)
```

This equivalent condition can be produced with `Simplify[cond]`, but I wanted to avoid `(Full)Simplify` because some of the transformations are only generically true.

***Question:***
Is there a way to get `Reduce` or an equivalently rigorous reduction to produce `False`?  The condition `cond` arose programmatically, so I don't have much control over its form.

Comment: Since there seems to be a bug with `FindInstance`, I should probably add that I'm using V11.3.0 (Jan 22, 2018), Mac OS.  I can add it to the question, if it turns out to be important.

Comment: `Reduce[cond]` works in place of `Reduce[cond, {x, y}]`....I guess I'll delete, unless someone argues this would be valuable Q&A.

Comment: `Reduce[cond, {y, x}]` works, too.  It's solving for `y` first that is the problem (`Reduce[cond, {y}]` fails).

Comment: Earlier `NotElement` oddity: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105511/strange-behaviour-of-notelement-in-reduce

Comment: And, `FindInstance[cond, {y, x}] ` returns an empty list, as it should.